# Draw 3D GameObject above GUI in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to draw a GameObject in front of all other components in my project and GUI Textures as well.

I created a second Camera and set Depth and Layer but it still not work. I hope you can help me to find the error or something I forgot.

Here is my MainScript which is drawing a simple Texture:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainScript : MonoBehaviour
{
Texture2D texture;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

    for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.blue);
        }
    }
    texture.Apply();
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), texture);
}
}
```

I also created two cameras and a GameObject which displays a GUI Texture. The Texture is visible in the preview screen but on runtime the Texture which is drawing in the MainScript is foregrounded.

I made two more Screenshots of my Camera Objects. See here:

[image]

[image]

I can also supply the whole project for you. It is just a basic test project.

Here is the link to the Project in Google Drive: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7OHj4zSEneLNGJRUXU0Zld2SzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

set depth of camera2 to camera1.depth+1, Clear Flags of camera2 to depth only and Clear Flags of camera1 to skybox. Uncheck GUILayer at Camera2 and check GUILayer in camera1. That should do it...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your response. Now it works in my project depending on the settings you told me.
In my case, I would like to have 3D Objects above GUITextures, which I am drawing in my C#-Scripts. Is this possible as well? There I am still stuck. Otherwise I will use you solution but it would be difficult to implement that in retrospect.

Comment: I've no idea what exactly you want. Unfortunately i've got an older version than you and I'm working on a Mac so I can't import your project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot draw 3D objects in front of the GUI elements, `OnGUI` code always renders in top of everything.

To achieve this you can use [Render Textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-RenderTexture.html) (Unity Pro only): have two cameras in your scene, place your 3D objects in one camera, render this camera to a texture, and finally use that texture as the source of a [`GUI.DrawTexture()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTexture.html).